# How do I NOT update a password field when it's left blank in $_POST?

Tags: php, forms, passwords

**UPDATE: I solved the problem myself and the answer is below. Carry on...**

I have a form for updating your account using PHP and mySQL. On submit, it assigns all of the $_POST variables to the new user() object, and then does an update() method on the user object which runs an UPDATE query in SQL.

The form obviously defaults to all of the user's information, EXCEPT for the password, which I don't prefill. It's blank unless they want to change their password.

If I didn't do anything to address this, every account update would reset the person's password to "", since the field is blank on submit. That would be bad. So to fix it, I added this code:

```
    if(empty($_POST['password']) || is_null($_POST['password']) || !isset($_POST['password']) || $_POST['password'] == "") {
        $user->hashed_password = $edituser->hashed_password;
    } else {
        $password = $database->escape_value($_POST['password']);
        $user->hashed_password = md5($password);
    }
```

Basically, if the $_POST password value is blank, set the password to the current user's password ($edituser is an object created in advance to save the current user's info if needed). Believe me, I tried it first with just if(empty()) because empty should work, but it didn't, so I added the null, the isset, and even the !== "" just to be safe.

No matter what I do, the password is reset to blank. Why?

Comment: empty() should be enough. Print the values of `$_POST['password']` and `$edituser->hashed_password` to see what's wrong.

Comment: You should NEVER use MD5 for passwords.

Learn more here: https://www.okta.com/identity-101/md5/#:~:text=MD5%20should%20not%20be%20used,chosen%20as%20a%20valid%20alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great, it turns out I'm just an idiot!

My User class has an attributes function that requires db field names to be identical to the object attribute names for it to work. My class attribute was $password, my db field name was "hashed_password" -- so it updated to blank no matter what.

That was a fun couple of hours!

Comment: I've been an idiot so many times :))

Answer (score 2):

Even if the  field is blank, it will still be present in $_POST.

```
$Password = trim(isset($_POST['Password']) ? $_POST['Password'] : '');

if($Password)
{
    //validate password
    //update password
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have warnings turn on? You might need to !isset($_POST['password']) first in your if statement

This has served me well with debugging stuff like this:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors','On');
```

Answer (score -1):

The simple way to solve this problem try:

```
$vEmployeeName = mysqli_real_escape_string($db->link,$_POST['vEmployeeName']);
$vPassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db->link, $_POST['vPassword']);

if($vPassword=="")
{
  $query = "update tblogin 
  set vEmployeeName='$vEmployeeName' 
  where iAutoId='$editid' ";
}
else
{
  $query = "update tblogin 
  set vEmployeeName='$vEmployeeName',
  vPassword=MD5('$vPassword') 
  where iAutoId='$editid' ";
}
```